# Import a Takeout of Photos?

Tags: google, import

I have an iCloud account for my iPhone.   My computer is Linux.  I have in hand a Google Takeout of about 600 photos.  How can I import them into iCloud?  I would like to preserve the metadata that is now in [photo].jpg.json files.

There are also a handful of videos.  Importing those too "would be nice."

Comment: Which information from your json files do you want to preserve? Is EXIF information present on your JPEG files or completely missing?

Comment: It seems you can join your JPEG files with JSON by bulk with exiftool https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024255/bulk-join-json-with-jpg-from-google-takeout

Comment: I think this will do it for me - thanks! 
Post it as an answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can join your JPEG files with JSON in bulk with exiftool.

See examples here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024255/bulk-join-json-with-jpg-from-google-takeout